# Magento 2: I need to run observer function through Cron job

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cron

I want to run an observer function through a Cron job. Can anyone share the simple observer function.?

Here is my code

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
     <group id="default">
         <job name="abandon_cron_test" instance="Abc\Abandon\Observer\Abandon" method="execute">
               <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
         </job>
     </group>
</config>
```

Observer file

> Abandon.php

```
class Abandon implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_objectManager;

    /**
    * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/abondoncronrunobserver.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('cron successfully');
    }
}
```

NO, there is no hard requirement to run the observer in cron. Here am using cron/run.php file to use in cronjob. But am not getting quote data in this file.

Here is my code:

```
  namespace ABC\Abandon\Cron;

    use \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    class Run {

    protected $logger;
    protected $scopeConfig;
    public function __construct(
    LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ){
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

    }


    public function execute(){

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $cartObj = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
    $quoteId = $cartObj->getQuote()->getId();
    $itemsArray = $cartObj->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    foreach($itemsArray as $item) {
    $productName[] = $item->getName();
    }
    if(is_array($productName)){
    $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
    }
    $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
    $abdata['quoteid'] = $quoteId;
    return $abdata;
    }

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot run an observer on cronjob

Comment: The observer need a parameter an  how you will get that  parameter

Comment: Also, I am running cron/run.php through cron but In this file I can't get the quote data for the cron job in cron/run.php. How I can do?

Comment: why you want to run cron with observer?

Comment: @Shiwani check this answer

Comment: Observers and Crons are two separate mechanisms and shouldn't be calling each other. If you have functionality in an Observer the needs to be executed elsewhere (like in a cron) then this is where Magento's best practice recommendations of using separation of concerns is useful. Create a simple class that performs your desired functionality. Using dependency injection require that class in both your Cron and Observer classes, and call the same function once you have the required data for any params.

Comment: Can you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

In this case, we could not get current customer quote from cron, from below code you will get all items productnames and quoteid in array you will need to get quote_id of customer and add in to filter:

> ABC/Abandon/etc/crontab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="custom_cronjob" instance="ABC\Abandon\Cron\Check" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

> ABC/Abandon/Cron/Check.php

```
<?php 
namespace Wagento\Australiapost\Cron;

class Check {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $itemCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $quoteCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quoteCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory,  
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository 
    ) {

        $this->quoteCollectionFactory = $quoteCollectionFactory;
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory;
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        $abdata = [];
        $productNames = $quoteId = '';
        $itemCollection =$this->itemCollectionFactory->create();

        // You can also filter the collection with below code
        /* 
        $itemCollection =$this->itemCollectionFactory->create()
        ->addFieldToSelect('created_at')
        ->addFieldToSelect('item_id')
        ->addFieldToSelect('quote_id')
        ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', ['eq' => $quoteID]);    */ 

        if (count($itemCollection)) {
            foreach ($itemCollection as $item)
            {
                $productName[] = $item->getName();
                $quoteIds[] = $item->getQuoteId();
            }
            if(!empty($productName)){
                $productNames .= implode(';',$productName);
            }
            if(!empty($quoteIds)){
                $quoteId .= implode(';',$quoteIds);
            }
            $abdata['productNames'] = $productNames;
            $abdata['quoteid'] = $quoteId;
        }
        return $abdata;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I am getting all the quote ids. But I need to get current quote id of the logged in account
For instance: test@gmail.com -- I want to get this email id's abandon products and quote id.

Comment: In cron you will not get current user session, you will get all the quote items. based on you need you will need to filter the collection.

Comment: How I can filter ?

Comment: $itemCollection =$this->itemCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', ['eq' => $quoteIDYouNeedToFilter]);

Comment: Need to get current login quote data(abandon cart data) of logged in User.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92305/discussion-between-shiwani-and-ashish-viradiya).

Comment: Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Good Post to describe the cron work, But Where i will see this result of $abdata ?When i see in var/log/cron.log it doesn't sho the result where these result get output @AshishViradiya